# Поменять кнопку на обратно действие Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular2, ionic

Есть приложение на Angular 5 (Ionic Framemowork 3).
В приложении есть кнопка возле каждого товара которая добавляет в избранные. Кнопка называется "Добавить". Товар сохраняется в localstorage
А мне нужно сделать так: после того как пользователь нажал на кнопку и добавил в избранные, нужно поменять название кнопки на "Удалить", и при нажатии на кнопку удалять товар с localstorage.
Помогите пожалуйста, подкиньте идею.

Comment: Надо на новой кнопке написать обработчик поиска и удаления товара из хранилища. Какой вопрос, такой ответ.

Comment: @Other ну а как по другому спросить? У меня есть две функции, одна добавляет, другая удаляет. Но как повесить две функции которые выполняются поочередно, на одну кнопку я не знаю.

Comment: А как Вы на первую повесили? Покажите Ваш код, покажите что сделали.

Comment: @Other Вот две кнопки, одна добавляет, другая удаляет

`<button ion-button class="addtocompare" (click)="addtocompare(item)">Compare</button>
  <button ion-button class="addtocompare" (click)="deletecompare(item)">Remove</button>`

Answer (score 0):

1 Можно добавить атрибут isSelected = false для каждого объекта товара

2 В кнопке выводить {{ item.isSelected ? 'Remove' : 'Compare'}}

3 Обработчик клика в файле *.ts в зависимости от условия isSelected

Comment: Товары я получаю с api и сохраняю в localstorage, и каждый раз как обновляется количество товаров все товары обновляются и обнуляется значение isSelected. Как это можно решить?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Нужно периодически дергать апи для получения обновлений? Если так, то нужно сопоставить обновленные товары с имеющимися в locaStorage и перенести значение isSelected

Comment: да, при запуске приложения дергается api на предмет количество товаров. Если api возврощает больше чем есть в приложении, загружаются все товары.
Но я понял, нужно догружать товары а не грузить все снова

Comment: В этом случае - конечно, это самый верный подход, если апи позволяет подгрузку, начиная с определенного id.
Тогда текущее состояние существующих товаров не будет перезаписываться.